# Spring с Hibernate. Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Вот мой XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vladhuk.examples"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_test?useSSL=false &amp; serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev"/>
        <property name="username" value="vladhuk"/>
        <property name="password" value="1"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.vladhuk.examples"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

При этом среда не распознает "packagesToScan":
[image]

Возможно проблема не в этом, но явно что-то не так с объявлением компонента.Пробовал добавлять свойство "annotatedClasses" - также безрезультатно.

Класс вызывающий ошибку (сомневаюсь, правда, что он как-то замешан):

```
@Repository
public class HibernateSpitterDao implements SpitterDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateSpitterDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;      
    }

    private Session currentSession() {             
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
    }                                              

    public void addSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
        currentSession().save(spitter);            

    }

    public Spitter getSpitterById(long id) {       // Использует текущий сеанс
        return currentSession().get(Spitter.class, id);
    }

    public void saveSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
        currentSession().update(spitter);           

    }
}
```

Оставлю еще зависимости на всякий случай:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Господи, какой старый код... Попробуй прописать данные к hibernate в `application.properies`. Вот [пример из статьи](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-mysql-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно было загрузить Session Factory из `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean`